# How can a PC on 10.x access wireless router in 192.x?

Tags: networking, routing

I have a PC on 10.x subnet. there is a wireless router connected to the 10.x main router, and wireless router is using 192.x as it's network IP range, as a way to keep the 2 networks isolated (wireless is for guest access and not allowing them to access 10.x)

From the PC, I cannot access the wireless router 192.x to view it's web interface config. 
to do so, I need to plug the PC directly into the wireless router and then change IP on PC to be on same subnet as wireless router. This gets annoying after a few beers, so I'm trying to research static routes to see if that is the way.

On the 10.x main router, do I setup a static route that says "when this ip address is requested, send the requests to this different ip address, on this different subnet"?

I think the command structure might be akin to...

```
ip route 
target_ip_in_10.x  
subnet_mask ? 255.255.255.0 (small network)  
ip of wireless router in other subnet
```

Is the subnet in the example above the subnet of the main ip range, class c 254 max addresses, so it's 255.255.255.0 ?

Do i just need to make sure the target_ip_in_10.x is never used by other devices in that subnet, or does static routing ensure that IP is never dhcp etc?

Does this ensure that traffic from the wireless router 192.x is still restricted from access the 10.x network?

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than that.

Simply configure the child router (the router connected as a downstream PC of the main router; 192.*) to allow remote administration.

You can then navigate to that router's external IP address (the IP address in 10.0.0.* assigned to its upstream port by the main router; visible in the main router's DHCP table or the child router ISP info) from anywhere in the main network.

Comment: i don't see how the parent router would know how to route requests to certain IP addresses through the child router though?

Comment: @WalrustheCat: It won't; the inner network will be isolated by NAT.